# Trying to divide two counts in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

so I'm trying to do simple division and of course SQL, being super logical that it is, makes it impossible. What I am trying to do is this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
1 - ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.DID) FROM TGAMAZING T AS NUM) * 100 /
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D.ID) FROM DIRECTORS D AS DENOM))
```

but how would I write this SQL (Oracle)?

Comment: is it oracle or sql-server?

Comment: give use an example row or 2, and an example output that you want

Comment: If you are looking for a SELECT with no FROM TABLE in Oracle (like MS SQL Server permits), just use `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` (yes, "dual" does the trick).

Comment: And being this or any other thing, your question could be clearer.

Comment: Its not about the actual tables but about the easiest way to do legal division on two different counts. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I suspect that what you meant to say was "...and of course SQL, being super logical that it is, can surely do this but I don't know enough to figure it out". Or, to paraphrase Shakespeare, "The fault, dear @AlexKornhauser, lies not in SQL, but in ourselves...". Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Oracle**

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34298/8

Method 1:

```
SELECT 1 - (COUNT(DISTINCT DID) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT ID))
FROM TGAMAZING
cross join DIRECTORS;
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT 1 - 
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DID) FROM TGAMAZING) * 100 /
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DIRECTORS)
    )
FROM DUAL;
```

**SQL Server**

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34298/3

Method 1

```
SELECT 1 - (COUNT(DISTINCT DID) * 100.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT ID))
FROM TGAMAZING
cross join DIRECTORS;
```

Method 2

```
SELECT 1 - 
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DID) FROM TGAMAZING) * 100.0 /
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM DIRECTORS)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the calculation as it were fields and use "FROM DUAL", as you don't want to query any of your tables.

```
SELECT  
  1 - ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.DID) FROM TGAMAZING T) * 100 /
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D.ID) FROM DIRECTORS D))
  AS RESULT
FROM DUAL
```

Reference: [Selecting from the DUAL Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm).

Comment: I don't think you can have the `...AS NUM` and `...AS DENOM` where  you've got them.

Comment: @BobJarvis Me neither :-) Edited. Thanks.